# Why does VLC superimpose an additional “shadow” image?

Tags: vlc

[image]

This "effect" has been regularly occuring on my Fedora 20 desktop the past few days. It seems strictly confined to VLC and does not affect any other video players I have installed.

I have played with VLC settings (including resetting to the factory default settings) as well as reinstalling the entire package with no luck. The only thing that seems to fix this is a complete reboot of my system.

Why does this occur and how can I fix this besides a reboot?

Comment: I'm not sure whether SU or here is more appropriate. I decided to ask here because I'm running Fedora but please feel free to migrate if you think it's more suitable on SU.

Comment: I think you'd be better served with this on SU, the issue is likely with VLC + Fedora. Let us know in comments we can assist w/ getting this migrated there. Don't just cross post it or it will get closed and annoy the main users.

Comment: @slm Yep, please help me get a mod to migrate. Cheers. :)

Comment: If you want to migrate, flag this question (use the link just above the comments) for moderator attention and ask them to migrate. Since this question is on topic both here and on [su], it will only be migrated at the request of the OP (you). However, this is actually a *nix specific problem, you might want to leave it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a issue with vlc's output module, you need to choose one that works with your X server/desktop environment. Open vlc's preferences, ad change your output module:

[image]

The specific one you need to use will depend on your system, try `X11 video output` and, if that doesn't work, try the others until you find one that does.